# Hibernate's Envers equivalent for golang (GORM) for auditing

Tags: go, go-gorm, hibernate-envers

We want a track the history of operations (audits) on all the entries of various tables in the database (PostgreSQL). The programming language is golang with GORM ( https://gorm.io/ ) as ORM.

Basically capturing the CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE operations on the tables in a separate (say audit_logs) table.

The desired schema of audit_logs table is:

- entity_class  // the table on which the operation has occurred
- entity_id     // the value of primary key on which operation has occurred, basically row's ref
- action        // the action, eg, CREATE, UPDATE or DELETE
- action_taker  // the user_id who has done the action (could be retrieved from request's context)
- prev_data     // json binary of data before the operation, (NULL in case of CREATE)
- cur_data      // json binary of data after the operation
- at            // the time at which operation has occurred

Such functionality is available in Hibernate's enver ( https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa#hibernate ).

However, for golang's GORM there isn't any such functionality.

Has anyone landed up on such requirement in golang. If yes, what was the approach or any solution was found/built? Any leads would be helpful.

We've tried registering the hooks on gorm.DB object.

say object for audit_log is

```golang
import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type AuditLog struct {
    EntityClass  string `gorm:"column:entity_class"`
    EntityID     string `gorm:"column:entity_id"`
    Action       string `gorm:"column:action"`
    ActionTaker  string `gorm:"column:action_taker"`
    PrevData     interface{} `gorm:"column:prev_data"`
    CurData      interface{} `gorm:"column:cur_data"`
    At           time.Time `gorm:"column:at"`
}
```

Now, in initialisation function of database, registered the hooks

```golang
    _ = db.AutoMigrate(&AuditLog{})  // creating the table if not exists

    _ = db.Callback().Create().After("gorm:create").Register("audit_log:create", auditLogCreateCallback)
    _ = db.Callback().Update().After("gorm:update").Register("audit_log:update", auditLogUpdateCallback)
    _ = db.Callback().Delete().After("gorm:delete").Register("audit_log:delete", auditLogDeleteCallback)
```

And defined the respective functions, eg,

```golang
func auditLogCreateCallback(db *gorm.DB) {
    if db.Error != nil {
        return
    }

    entityName := db.Statement.Table

    // here we need to extract the information from db.Statement object (OR other location if required)
    // basically we need EntityID, PrevData and CurData here
    // but db.Statement.Dest or db.Statement.Model both contains data indifferent forms in different situation (eg, sometimes updated via map, sometimes via model itself). Also, incase of bulk inserts / conditional edits (eg, update product's discount where product category is 'xyz') the data is stored different in the db.Statement model.

    usernameInterface := db.Statement.Context.Value(constant.UserId)
    username, _ := usernameInterface.(string)

    auditLog := AuditLog{
        EntityClass:  entityName,
        EntityID:     "<id here>",
        Action:       "CREATE",
        ActionTaker:  username,
        PrevData:     "<json dump of prev data>",
        CurData:      "<json dump of cur data>",
        At:           time.Now(),
    }

    auditDB.Create(&auditLog)
}
```

Comment: I found this article https://aayushacharya.com.np/blog/audit-log-gorm/ that was helpful